# Cypress as UI test automation tool for Salesforce

Tags: test-setup, test-automation

Does anyone have experience using Cypress as a UI test automation tool for a Salesforce based project? If so, what are the drawbacks, constraints or implications, e.g. regarding login or possible restrictions on access to certain UI elements?

I have also read some articles that state that it should be generally possible to use Cypress:

- [Growing a Salesforce Testing Strategy with Cypress](https://www.phase2technology.com/blog/growing-a-salesforce-testing-strategy-with-cypress)
- [Using Cypress to test in Salesforce](https://medium.com/smartbox-engineering/using-cypress-to-test-in-salesforce-a0699afe09b7)
- [How Optimizely used Cypress.io to automate testing within its AppExchange App in Salesforce](https://medium.com/engineers-optimizely/how-optimizely-used-cypress-io-to-automate-testing-within-its-appexchange-app-in-salesforce-3ee161948f02)

I still wonder if it makes sense to take the effort to integrate the use of Cypress in larger projects, perhaps for automated testing in a separate sandbox, or if unit tests for LWCs with Jest and for the Apex backend code are sufficient?

Comment: welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to visit the [help], scroll through the [tour], and read [ask]. In terms of your question, "Is It possible" - yes. Have you started using it? Do you have a specific concern?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main drawback is that the unit tests of Cypress and similar solutions modify the server state permanently. Jest-based testing for the client and Apex-based testing for the server is sufficient to test most types of logic. The only things they cannot catch are incompatible API changes between the client and server (e.g. changing a property name that is sent across the wire). These are usually caught in other phases of testing anyways, so it's not important to test these automatically in most cases.

That's not to say there are no benefits, but it comes with significant risk as well. Poorly designed tests in Jest and Apex can't affect server data, but poorly designed tests in Cypress, etc could have devastating consequences to your data. Ultimately, this is a risk-based assessment. It is up to you to determine if you are willing to accept the potential risks in exchange for the rather limited benefits of such testing.

A balanced approach would probably be to use Jest and Apex for as much testing as possible, and bridge the gap with Cypress only for full integration testing. That said, as far as I'm aware, Visualforce and Aura components can't be tested using something like Jest, so there is room for Cypress and other browser-based tooling for those kinds of testing.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, due to the data manipulation there was anyway the consideration to run these kind of tests in a separate sandbox.

Comment: @SebastianoVierk Yes, that would be an ideal scenario. Glad I was able to help clarify things.

Comment: @sfdcfox What is the tool/framework that is solid to use for Salesforce Test Automation? I have used Selenium, Cypress but that is not reliable. Whether the AI tools like Testim, TOSCA supports well?